# Email customer when price changes on the product

Tags: php, configurable-product, price, variables

At the moment I have managed to create a form that will insert product_ID, customer_Email and customer_Price to a table I created in The database.

the customer inputs there email and desired price.

I need some sort of script that when its ran, will check the table column product_ID and if customer_Price is more than the actual product_ID_Price then output a string.

I can think about the email part another time.

All the products are configurable products.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Mike Tim Turner,
Open this following url, it may helps to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817069/automatic-mail-alert-to-customers-on-new-products-arrival-in-magento